# Can MySQL transaction rollback without ROLLBACK query?

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I'm working on a financial system and I've got a problem with the MySQL transactions.

The system is a simple stock exchange, where users can buy and sell virtual shares. To keep integrity in buy and sell process I use transactions.
The problem is that in some cases (I don't know what it depends on) some of transactions are rolled back (or not commited), but next queries are processed.

The process is following:

1. User wants to buy shares for 1000 USD
2. In orderbook there are 4 offers for 250 USD
3. `START TRANSACTION`
4. For every offer:
5. Script does a UPDATE query (moving USD from one user to another and shares in the opposite way). Then script INSERTs entries to history tables.
6. Users pay a fee (UPDATE balances).
7. Repeat 5 and 6 for the next offer.
8. `COMMIT`

Now the key part - in some cases changes from point 5 are not saved, but from the 6 they are (I see that fee was paid, but there is no transaction in the history).
I'm not using `ROLLBACK` during this transactions and the script is not breaking (because in this case fee wouldn't be paid).

Is there any possibility that transaction is rolling back without `ROLLBACK` query? Or can MySQL COMMIT only few newest queries instead of all?

Comment: No, a transaction should always be atomic. Either it does everything or nothing.

Comment: The first hole in your system is that you check the orderbook (only) before your transaction, so it could have been changed; e.g. order 1 could have been used, leaving only 3 open offers, and depending on your actual code, step 5 might not do anything but step 6 might still charge the fee. But that's only one problem, and only in your concept. There are a lot of other things you can do wrong (e.g. using myisam, using wrong transaction level, not locking selects, ...), so there might be other issues here. And if you trade with real money/values, you should get a consultant to check your code.

Comment: I didn't write about that in the first post (sorry), but I lock the rows using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` before I start process.
When I'm processing single offers I'm checking additionaly, if the offer still exists, users have valid balances etc.
However currently it's demo system.

Comment: I still think that the most likely suspect is that you simply execute 6 even if you don't execute 5 when the checks fail. And your check 2 HAS to (also) happen inside the transaction. But if you don't add your actual code (which might be too much for stackoverflow, but you might try codereview) and also don't add all details like `for update` or additional checks, we cannot tell you where the wrong behaviour comes from. But we can assure you: the error is somewhere in your code, your data or your setup. There is no possibility that a (working) transaction is just partly executed.

Comment: I assume the `FOR UPDATE` is _after_ step 3?  Do you check for errors after every SQL, including the `COMMIT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's long time since the question was asked, but the problem actually was that I didn't check for the SQL errors for every query.

Actually at some points, when I should rollback transaction, I didn't do it.

If your are looking for answer - check again if you testing ALL queries in your transaction for successful execution and don't trust that the framework you are using is doing it for you automatically (just check it again).

Answer (score 2):

Transactions or not, it's the responsibility of your client code to verity that all your INSERT or UPDATE queries complete successfully and then either issue a explicit ROLLBACK or close the connection withour COMMIT to issue an implicity ROLLBACK. If any of them fails but your code goes on, those queries will not take effect (because they failed) but the rest will do.

Here's a simplified example:

```
mysql> create table test (
    ->     id int(10) unsigned not null,
    ->     primary key (id)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into test(id) values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test(id) values (2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test(id) values (-3);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1
```

We should have rollbacked and aborted here, but we didn't.

```
mysql> insert into test(id) values (4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  4 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

4 rows expected, got 3.

Other than that, there're many circumstances where you can get an unwanted COMMIT but an unwanted ROLLBACK is something I'm not sure that can happen unless you terminate a session with pending changes.